# How to avoid maintenance fee when balance drops below minimum?

Tags: credit-card, fees, debit-card, online-payment, cryptocurrency

Looking for a way to, in the event of a purchase dropping my balance below the minimum daily balance (MDB) with no way to bring it above the MDB before the end of the day, make 6 point of sale (POS) purchases that funnel back into my account (same bank or different bank) for free or at least less than the maintenance fee . It's important to know that the 6 POS purchases will enable me to avoid the maintenance fee, as per the account's policy, while having a balance below the MDB.

As far as I can tell, maintenance fees for MDB violations are recorded and then posted (as debit) in that cycle's statement when other maintenance-fee-avoiding transaction activities are not made within the 30-day cycle.

So, for example, if the MDB is $5000, and I make a $1000 purchase, and I don't replenish the account to $5000 by the end of the day, the maintenance fee will be avoided ***IF*** I made 6 POS purchases within the same cycle period. In this case, 6 POS purchases, the dip to a $4000 MDB will be recorded, but not posted as debit.

The idea here is that I don't want to spend money to avoid a fee in the event that the account can't be replenished to the MDB.

---

I was thinking something like donating 1¢ to my same-bank business account through my website 6 times (PayPal). Any proposed method doesn't have to be exactly free, but at least less than $5.

Comment: I have no idea how this method is supposed to work. You want to **buy** things using your debit card and this somehow **increases** the amount in the bank account so that it does not fall below the minimum daily balance needed to avoid maintenance fees?

Comment: Let me be more clear: The account in question allows for there not to be a maintenance fee if 6 POS purchases are made before the end of the statement cycle (1 month).

Comment: So the next 6 times that you visit Starbucks or Caribou Coffee and pay for your coffee with your debit card, and you are all set? You don't need to maintain the $5000 minimum balance as long as you use your debit card six times a month? Is there a fee for each debit card use?

Comment: Perhaps my question is too technical and unorthodox for people who use their debit card. I don't use the debit card linked to this particular account.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, yes, I do not need to maintain the MDB as long as I use my debit card 6 times. I use cash, and I use personal checks. I don't use electronic payment for this particular account.

Comment: `when noticed by the bank staff` - Almost certainly, this is entirely automated and no human even glances at your account.

Comment: That's right, I just spoke with the manager of my bank and we got into detail about it. I ended up making a program to keep me in line.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have three options:

1. Keep a $5000 MDB
2. Make 6 POS transactions a month
3. Call the bank and ask for the fee to be waived (probably will only work 1-3 times/year)

Outside of this you might need to look for a different type of account.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm aware of the waiver method, but I still think there is a legal way to avoid the fee using the Internet.

Comment: Yes, use you card 6 times at a POS system.  The bank collects fee for allowing the vendor to use your card.  They don't care where you use it. Your website doesn't get charged to allow / for using card transactions?